# Plotting with GLMMadaptive for zero-inflated, semi-continuous data?

Tags: r

I'm trying to utilize the effectPlotData as described here: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/GLMMadaptive/vignettes/Methods_MixMod.html

But, I'm trying to apply it to a model (two-part mixed model for zero-inflated semi-continuous data) that includes random/fixed effects for both a linear and logistic portion (hurdle lognormal). I get the following error: 
'Error in Qs[1, ] : incorrect number of dimensions'

Which, I think is from having more than one set of random/fixed effect outcomes, but if anyone else has come across this error or can advise, it would be appreciated! I've tried changing the terms in the new data frame and tried a couple of different options with length.out (attempted this as number of subjects and then number of total observations across all subjects), but get the same error each time.

Code below, specifies the model into m and new data frame into nDF:

```
m = mixed_model(Y~X, random = ~1|Subject,
                data = data_combined_temp_Fix_Num3,
                family = hurdle.lognormal,
                n_phis = 1, zi_fixed = ~X , zi_random = ~1|Subject,
                na.action = na.exclude)


nDF <- with(data_combined_temp_Fix_Num3,
            expand.grid(X = seq(min(X), max(X), length.out = 908),
                        Y = levels(Y)))


effectPlotData(m, nDF)
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to work for with the following example:

```
library("GLMMadaptive")

set.seed(1234)
n <- 100 # number of subjects
K <- 8 # number of measurements per subject
t_max <- 5 # maximum follow-up time

# we constuct a data frame with the design: 
# everyone has a baseline measurment, and then measurements at random follow-up times
DF <- data.frame(id = rep(seq_len(n), each = K),
                 time = c(replicate(n, c(0, sort(runif(K - 1, 0, t_max))))),
                 sex = rep(gl(2, n/2, labels = c("male", "female")), each = K))

# design matrices for the fixed and random effects non-zero part
X <- model.matrix(~ sex * time, data = DF)
Z <- model.matrix(~ time, data = DF)
# design matrices for the fixed and random effects zero part
X_zi <- model.matrix(~ sex, data = DF)
Z_zi <- model.matrix(~ 1, data = DF)

betas <- c(-2.13, -0.25, 0.24, -0.05) # fixed effects coefficients non-zero part
sigma <- 0.5 # standard deviation error terms non-zero part
gammas <- c(-1.5, 0.5) # fixed effects coefficients zero part
D11 <- 0.5 # variance of random intercepts non-zero part
D22 <- 0.1 # variance of random slopes non-zero part
D33 <- 0.4 # variance of random intercepts zero part

# we simulate random effects
b <- cbind(rnorm(n, sd = sqrt(D11)), rnorm(n, sd = sqrt(D22)), rnorm(n, sd = sqrt(D33)))
# linear predictor non-zero part
eta_y <- as.vector(X %*% betas + rowSums(Z * b[DF$id, 1:2, drop = FALSE]))
# linear predictor zero part
eta_zi <- as.vector(X_zi %*% gammas + rowSums(Z_zi * b[DF$id, 3, drop = FALSE]))
# we simulate log-normal longitudinal data
DF$y <- exp(rnorm(n * K, mean = eta_y, sd = sigma))
# we set the zeros from the logistic regression
DF$y[as.logical(rbinom(n * K, size = 1, prob = plogis(eta_zi)))] <- 0

###############################################################################

km1 <- mixed_model(y ~ sex * time, random = ~ 1 | id, data = DF, 
                   family = hurdle.lognormal(),
                   zi_fixed = ~ sex)

km1


nDF <- with(DF, expand.grid(time = seq(min(time), max(time), length.out = 15),
                            sex = levels(sex)))

plot_data <- effectPlotData(km1, nDF)

library("lattice")
xyplot(pred + low + upp ~ time | sex, data = plot_data,
       type = "l", lty = c(1, 2, 2), col = c(2, 1, 1), lwd = 2,
       xlab = "Follow-up time", ylab = "")

local({
    km1$Funs$mu_fun <- function (eta) {
        pmax(exp(eta + 0.5 * exp(2 * km1$phis)), .Machine$double.eps)
    }
    km1$family$linkfun <- function (mu) log(mu)
    plot_data <- effectPlotData(km1, nDF)

    xyplot(exp(pred) + exp(low) + exp(upp) ~ time | sex, data = plot_data,
           type = "l", lty = c(1, 2, 2), col = c(2, 1, 1), lwd = 2,
           xlab = "Follow-up time", ylab = "")
})
```

Comment: Thanks! I was able to counter my issue and get a plot, but I will also take a look at your script! I didn't put it in the original code for brevity, but I was parsing my original dataframe for subjects with enough data. When I added this parsing to the variables I was calling within nDF, I was able to get the dimensions to match.

Comment: Is there anything similar for effectPlotData, for specifying the type of model you want to estimate, as you've specified for the predict function (e.g., type = c("zero_part"; https://drizopoulos.github.io/GLMMadaptive/reference/methods.html)?

Comment: @troychris123 No `effectPlotData()` produces the effects for the mean of the model.

Comment: dimitris rizopoulus, thank you for your response, but I'm not entirely sure what mean of the model refers to here and hoping to better understand. In your example, is effectPlotData using the fixed effects from the linear portion or is it also using the fixed effect from the zero-part? I was assuming that the linear mixed model and the zero-part were two separate processes (zero-part acting as a logistic between zero and non-zero y data), and so you could plot based on two sets of coefficients (one based on the linear and one from logistic). Is this the wrong interpretation?

Answer (score 0):

In case someone comes across the same error, I was filtering data from my data frame within the model -- which caused the dimensions of the model and the variable from the data frame to not match. I applied the same filtering to the new data frame (I've also moved forward with a completely new data frame that only includes trials that are actually used by the model so that no filtering has to be used at any step).

```
m = mixed_model(Y~X, random = ~1|Subject,
 data = data_combined_temp_Fix_Num3[data_combined_temp_Fix_Num3$Z>=4 &
 data_combined_temp_Fix_Num3$ZZ>= 4,],
 family = hurdle.lognormal,
 n_phis = 1, zi_fixed = ~X , zi_random = ~1|Subject,
 na.action = na.exclude)`


nDF <- with(data_combined_temp_Fix_Num3,
  expand.grid(X = seq(min(X[data_combined_temp_Fix_Num3$Z>= 4 &     
  data_combined_temp_Fix_Num3$ZZ>= 4])),
  max(X[data_combined_temp_Fix_Num3$Z>= 4 &
  data_combined_temp_Fix_Num3$ZZ>= 4])), length.out = 908),
  Y = levels(Y)))`


effectPlotData(m, nDF)
```